# How to calculate ranging by a few conditions?

Tags: mysql, database, join, select, histogram

I have 2 tables:

```
activity
user_id login_time
1       2018-04-15
2       2018-04-18
3       2018-04-19
3       2018-04-20
1       2018-04-20
2       2018-04-20
4       2018-04-20
```

--

```
payments
user_id     amount
  1            10
  1            30
  2            100
  3            35
  4            0
```

I'm looking for number of users, which have login_time = 20.04.2018 by grops.

Desired result on 20.04.2018:

```
total_amount  number of users
0-10               1
10-20              0
30-50              2
50-and more        1
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case when and inner join

```
select case when amount<=10 then '0-10' when amount>10 and amount<20 then '10-20'
when amount>=30 and amount<50 then '30-50'
when amount>=50 then '50-and more' end as total_amount,count(payments.user_id)
from payments inner join activity on payments.user_id=activity.user_id
where login_time='2018-04-20'
group by case when amount<=10 then '0-10' when amount>10 and amount<20 then '10-20'
when amount>=30 and amount<50 then '30-50'
when amount>=50 then '50-and more' end
```

Comment: yes, there was a spelling mistake, i corrected it, you can check now

Comment: can you fix , because empty set, please?

Comment: let me check please

Comment: yes , I saw.
But how do U think, why it displays empty set on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.amount < 10 THEN '0-10'
  WHEN b.amount < 20 THEN '11-20'
  WHEN b.amount < 30 THEN '21-30'
  WHEN b.amount < 40 THEN '31-40'
  WHEN b.amount < 50 THEN '41-50'
  ELSE '50 and more' END AS total_amount,
  count(DISTINCT b.user_id) AS number_of_users 
FROM activity a
JOIN payments b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE a.login_time = '2018-04-18'
GROUP BY 1
```

If in the activity tables users can appear only once p/day you can use count(*) instead of count(DISTINCT user_id).

Hope it helps

Comment: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous
mysql>